# Arithmetic operations between constants

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, compile-time-constant

Consider this code;

```
#define A 5
#define B 3

int difference = A - B;
```

does value of "difference" is hardcoded as "2" in compile time, or does it get calculated on runtime?

Comment: How could you tell the difference? The C standard has an "as-if" rule, which means that if you can't tell the difference, the implementation can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Disassemble the code, that's how. I probably would not use a compiler which did not reduce that to a 2; I would not consider it viable, unless it was the only way to target C to a platform that itself was overwhelmingly viable.

Comment: I know from first-hand experience that the free version of the [Microchip XC8](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc) compiler doesn't. You have to purchase the optimizing version to get something as rudimentary as compile time constant evaluation. At the time I circumvented the restriction via `enum` constant evaluation but it would have been unviable for a project of any size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `A` and `B` macros are a bit of a distraction.  This:

```
#define A 5
#define B 3

int difference = A - B;
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
int difference = 5 - 3;
```

so let's discuss the latter.

`5 - 3` is a *constant expression*, which is an expression that "can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be".  It's also an *integer constant expression".  For example, a case label must be an integer constant expression, so you could write either this:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 2: /* this is a constant */
    ...
}
```

or this:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 5 - 3: /* this is a constant expression */
    ...
}
```

But note that the definition says that it *can be* evaluated during translation, not that it must be.  There are some contexts that require constant expressions, and in those contexts the expression *must* be evaluated at compile time.

But assuming that `difference` is declared inside some function, the initializer is not one of those contexts.

Any compiler worth what you pay for it (even if it's free) will reduce `5 - 3` to `2` at compile time, and generate code that stores the value `2` in `difference`.  But it's not required to do so.  The C standard specifies the *behavior* of programs; it doesn't specify how that behavior must be implemented.  But it's safe to assume that whatever compiler you're using will replace `5 - 3` by `2`.

Even if you write:

```
int difference = 2;
```

a compiler could legally generate code that loads the value `5` into a register, subtracts `3` from it, and stores the contents of the register into `difference`.  That would be a silly thing to do, but the language standard doesn't exclude it.

As long as the final result is that `difference` has the value `2`, the language standard doesn't care how it's done.

On the other hand, if you write:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 5 - 3: /* ... */
    case 2:     /* ... */
}
```

then the compiler *must* compute the result so it can diagnose the error (you can't have two case labels with the same value.

Finally, if you define `difference` at file scope (outside any function), then the initial value *does* have to be constant.  But the real distinction in that case is not whether `5 - 3` will be evaluated at compile time, it's whether you're *allowed* to use a non-constant expression.

Reference: The latest draft of the 2011 C standard is [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (large PDF); constant expressions are discussed in section 6.6.

Comment: +1 very nice, detailed answer.  I considered going into more depth... but then I remembered I was at work :D

Answer (score 6):

The standard does not specify this sort of thing.  It says nothing about potential optimizations like this (and for good reason.  A standard defines semantics, not implementation).

Why not look at the disassembly for your compiler?  That will give you a definitive answer.

...

So let's do that.

Here is the output from VC++ 10:

```
#include <iostream>

#define A 5
#define B 3

int main() {
    int x = A - B;
    std::cout << x;  // make sure the compiler doesn't toss it away
010A1000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (10A2048h)]  
010A1006  push        2  
010A1008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (10A2044h)]  
    return 0;
010A100E  xor         eax,eax
```

As you can see, it just replaced the occurrence of `x` with a static value of 2 and pushed it onto the stack for the call to `cout`.  It did not evaluate the expression at runtime.

Comment: Examining the code generated by your compiler will give you an answer that's only definitive *for that compiler* (with the particular settings you used).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Any decent optimizing compiler will do this.  I said that it is unspecified by the standard, so obviously this applies to your compiler.  True I did miss the C tag, but the answer isn't going to be any different.